# How is AngularJS's $http function built?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How is the `$http` function in AngularJS built?

I can invoke it: `$http({})`…
Or access one of its properties `$http.post();`

How to build a javascript object / function that can be invoked, and has invokable properties?

Comment: You want to build the $http service by yourself ? Don't get your question.

Comment: actually I'm finished it, and and implemented small part of promises(then, success, error), now i will add native suport to rest. I knew that functions are objects too, My mistake was trying to use 'this' keyword and create an instance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript function is also an object. So it can have (and it has) properties. For example simplified code:

```
function $http(config) {
    console.log('generic ajax request');
}

$http.post = function(url, config) {
    console.log('post request');
}

$http();       // generic ajax request 
$http.post();  // post request
```